# What is current documentation tool for Rust?

Tags: rust, documentation

As far as I remember a new tool was under development a few years ago that named [Doxidize](https://github.com/steveklabnik/doxidize). But it seems its development has been stopped.

What's current documentation tool of Rust? Where can I see the source code? I am trying to use its source code to extract data schema from Rust source code.

Comment: Are you looking for  `cargo doc` or something else?

Comment: @Simson It seems it hasn't been changed. I remember there was a command to emit type informations in JSON form. Do you know something about it?